# TimeStamp in Control File

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, controlfile

I have a script that takes a table name and generates a control file by querying all the columns/rows the table.  This works fine for numeric and character data but fails on timestamp data so I need to adjust the script to output the timestamp data into the control in such a way that it can be read in properly.

So essentially, my question is how to format TimeStamp data in a control file so that it can be inputed into a TimeStamp column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `to_date` in your column listing as demonstrated [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2ALoader_FAQ#Can_one_modify_data_as_the_database_gets_loaded.3F).  Something like:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE some_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
(  col1
   col2        "to_date(:col2, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')"
)
BEGINDATA
foo,2008-09-17 13:00:00
bar,2008-09-17 13:30:05
```